# SQL Server - Multiple running totals

Tags: sql-server, performance, query, scalability

I've got a base table with transactions and I need to create a table with running totals. I need them to be per account and and also have a few running totals for each account (depending on the transaction type), and inside that, some running totals per sub-account.

My base table has these fields (more or less) :

```
AccountID  |  SubAccountID   |  TransactionType  |  TransactionAmount
```

Considering I've got about 4 types of running totals per Account/TransactionType and 2 more running totals per Account/SubAccount/TransactionType , and I've got about 2M accounts with about 10 sub accounts each, and I'm getting about 10K transactions every minute (at maximum load), how would you do it?

It's also a must that this run asynchronously via an SQL job, creating the aggregations without being part of the transactions themselves.

I'm pretty stuck using a cursor here - which takes way too long. I'd really appreciate any advice / articles that are doing more or less the same.

Comment: Accounting standard approach is to keep the running totals already in a table. I store with every transaction not only the old value but also the new value of the account.
You're not stuck using a cursor here, as this can be done in one sql SELECT statement.

Comment: Are you on SQL Server 2000, or are there other restrictions keeping you from using the window functions (ROW_NUMBER, RANK, etc)?

Comment: Our accounting system has had problems when running totals were stored in a separate physical table. Our vendor's software could update actual transactions without updating the actual balance table, resulting in an operating balance out of whack. A well designed system can avoid this, but be careful and consider how important accuracy is if you go the separate table approach.

Comment: Why is this a requirement, and what is attempting to be accomplished?  Depending on need, you could probably query the transaction table on request for the ('current') specified data, and move/aggregate rows at end-of-day (data warehousing, which I'm sure SQL Server provides utilities for).

Comment: I am limited to SQL Server 2005.
I don't have to have the last total always accurate, but I do have to keep all the running totals for every action made - a "History" table.

TomTom - I won't keep this with the original table - I need a few running totals of different transaction types and they don't belong in the original table. I don't think this can be done only with a SELECT - it's either a cursor or a while loop. I'd love to learn otherwise. 

X-Zero - This is a kind of data warehousing procedure. I just need it done about every minute and not once a day.

Comment: if you really do not want to keep running totals in your table, you can just calculate it in C# - simple and fast.

Answer (score 7):

Asynchronous implies that the running totals do not need to be completely accurate at all times, or your data change patterns are such that a one-off running total build will be valid and accurate until the next load.  Anyway, I'm sure you have thought that part through, so I won't labour the point.

Your main options for a high-performance, supported, method are a SQLCLR function/procedure, or an `UPDATE` based on Hugo Kornelis' set-based iteration method.  The SQLCLR method (implemented in a procedure, but reasonably easy to translate) can be found [here](http://dataeducation.com/running-sums-yet-again-sqlclr-saves-the-day/).

I haven't been able to find Hugo's method online, but it is detailed in the excellent MVP Deep Dives (Volume 1).  Sample code to illustrate Hugo's method (copied from one of my posts on another site you may not have a login for) is shown below:

```
-- A work table to hold the reformatted data, and
-- ultimately, the results
CREATE  TABLE #Work
    (
    Acct_No         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    MonthDate       DATETIME NOT NULL,
    MonthRate       DECIMAL(19,12) NOT NULL,
    Amount          DECIMAL(19,12) NOT NULL,
    InterestAmount  DECIMAL(19,12) NOT NULL,
    RunningTotal    DECIMAL(19,12) NOT NULL,
    RowRank         BIGINT NOT NULL
    );

-- Prepare the set-based iteration method
WITH    Accounts
AS      (
        -- Get a list of the account numbers
        SELECT  DISTINCT Acct_No 
        FROM    #Refunds
        ),
        Rates
AS      (
        -- Apply all the accounts to all the rates
        SELECT  A.Acct_No,
                R.[Year],
                R.[Month],
                MonthRate = R.InterestRate / 12
        FROM    #InterestRates R
        CROSS 
        JOIN    Accounts A
        ),
        BaseData
AS      (
        -- The basic data we need to work with
        SELECT  Acct_No = ISNULL(R.Acct_No,''),
                MonthDate = ISNULL(DATEADD(MONTH, R.[Month], DATEADD(YEAR, R.[year] - 1900, 0)), 0),
                R.MonthRate,
                Amount = ISNULL(RF.Amount,0),
                InterestAmount = ISNULL(RF.Amount,0) * R.MonthRate,
                RunningTotal = ISNULL(RF.Amount,0)
        FROM    Rates R
        LEFT
        JOIN    #Refunds RF
                ON  RF.Acct_No = R.Acct_No
                AND RF.[Year] = R.[Year]
                AND RF.[Month] = R.[Month]
        )
-- Basic data plus a rank id, numbering the rows by MonthDate, and resetting to 1 for each new Account
INSERT  #Work
        (Acct_No, MonthDate, MonthRate, Amount, InterestAmount, RunningTotal, RowRank)
SELECT  BD.Acct_No, BD.MonthDate, BD.MonthRate, BD.Amount, BD.InterestAmount, BD.RunningTotal,
        RowRank = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY BD.Acct_No ORDER BY MonthDate)
FROM    BaseData BD;

-- An index to speed the next stage (different from that used with the Quirky Update method)
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX nc1 ON #Work (RowRank, Acct_No);

-- Iteration variables
DECLARE @Rank       BIGINT,
        @RowCount   INTEGER;

-- Initialize
SELECT  @Rank = 1,
        @RowCount = 1;

-- This is the iteration bit, processes a rank id per iteration
-- The number of rows processed with each iteration is equal to the number of groups in the data
-- More groups --> greater efficiency
WHILE   (1 = 1)
BEGIN
        SET @Rank = @Rank + 1;

        -- Set-based update with running totals for the current rank id
        UPDATE  This
        SET     InterestAmount = (Previous.RunningTotal + This.Amount) * This.MonthRate,
                RunningTotal = Previous.RunningTotal + This.Amount + (Previous.RunningTotal + This.Amount) * This.MonthRate
        FROM    #Work This
        JOIN    #Work Previous
                ON  Previous.Acct_No = This.Acct_No
                AND Previous.RowRank = @Rank - 1
        WHERE   This.RowRank = @Rank;

        IF  (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) BREAK;
END;

-- Show the results in natural order
SELECT  *
FROM    #Work
ORDER   BY
        Acct_No, RowRank;
```

In SQL Server 2012, you could use the windowing function extensions e.g. `SUM OVER (ORDER BY)`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you want asynchronous, but a couple of indexed view sounds like just the ticket here. If you want a simple SUM per some group that is: define running total.

If you really want asynchronous, with 160 new rows per second your running totals will always be out of date. Asynchronous would mean no triggers or indexed views

Answer (score 5):

Calculating running totals is notoriously slow, whether you do it with a cursor or with a triangular join. It is very tempting to denormalize, to store running totals in a column, especially if you select it frequently. However, as usual when you denormalize, you need to guarantee the integrity of your denormalized data. Fortunately, you can guarantee the integrity of running totals with constraints – as long as all your constraints are trusted, all your running totals are correct.

Also this way you can easily ensure that the current balance (running totals) is never negative - enforcing by other methods can also be very slow. The following script demonstrates the technique.

```
    CREATE TABLE Data.Inventory(InventoryID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
      ItemID INT NOT NULL,
      ChangeDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
      ChangeQty INT NOT NULL,
      TotalQty INT NOT NULL,
      PreviousChangeDate DATETIME NULL,
      PreviousTotalQty INT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT PK_Inventory PRIMARY KEY(ItemID, ChangeDate),
      CONSTRAINT UNQ_Inventory UNIQUE(ItemID, ChangeDate, TotalQty),
      CONSTRAINT UNQ_Inventory_Previous_Columns UNIQUE(ItemID, PreviousChangeDate, PreviousTotalQty),
      CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Self FOREIGN KEY(ItemID, PreviousChangeDate, PreviousTotalQty)
        REFERENCES Data.Inventory(ItemID, ChangeDate, TotalQty),
      CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_Valid_TotalQty CHECK(TotalQty >= 0 AND (TotalQty = COALESCE(PreviousTotalQty, 0) + ChangeQty)),
      CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_Valid_Dates_Sequence CHECK(PreviousChangeDate < ChangeDate),
      CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_Valid_Previous_Columns CHECK((PreviousChangeDate IS NULL AND PreviousTotalQty IS NULL)
                OR (PreviousChangeDate IS NOT NULL AND PreviousTotalQty IS NOT NULL))
    );
    GO
    -- beginning of inventory for item 1
    INSERT INTO Data.Inventory(ItemID,
      ChangeDate,
      ChangeQty,
      TotalQty,
      PreviousChangeDate,
      PreviousTotalQty)
    VALUES(1, '20090101', 10, 10, NULL, NULL);
    -- cannot begin the inventory for the second time for the same item 1
    INSERT INTO Data.Inventory(ItemID,
      ChangeDate,
      ChangeQty,
      TotalQty,
      PreviousChangeDate,
      PreviousTotalQty)
    VALUES(1, '20090102', 10, 10, NULL, NULL);


Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 10
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UNQ_Inventory_Previous_Columns'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Data.Inventory'.
The statement has been terminated.

-- add more
DECLARE @ChangeQty INT;
SET @ChangeQty = 5;
INSERT INTO Data.Inventory(ItemID,
  ChangeDate,
  ChangeQty,
  TotalQty,
  PreviousChangeDate,
  PreviousTotalQty)
SELECT TOP 1 ItemID, '20090103', @ChangeQty, TotalQty + @ChangeQty, ChangeDate, TotalQty
  FROM Data.Inventory
  WHERE ItemID = 1
  ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC;

SET @ChangeQty = 3;
INSERT INTO Data.Inventory(ItemID,
  ChangeDate,
  ChangeQty,
  TotalQty,
  PreviousChangeDate,
  PreviousTotalQty)
SELECT TOP 1 ItemID, '20090104', @ChangeQty, TotalQty + @ChangeQty, ChangeDate, TotalQty
  FROM Data.Inventory
  WHERE ItemID = 1
  ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC;

SET @ChangeQty = -4;
INSERT INTO Data.Inventory(ItemID,
  ChangeDate,
  ChangeQty,
  TotalQty,
  PreviousChangeDate,
  PreviousTotalQty)
SELECT TOP 1 ItemID, '20090105', @ChangeQty, TotalQty + @ChangeQty, ChangeDate, TotalQty
  FROM Data.Inventory
  WHERE ItemID = 1
  ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC;

-- try to violate chronological order

SET @ChangeQty = 5;
INSERT INTO Data.Inventory(ItemID,
  ChangeDate,
  ChangeQty,
  TotalQty,
  PreviousChangeDate,
  PreviousTotalQty)
SELECT TOP 1 ItemID, '20081231', @ChangeQty, TotalQty + @ChangeQty, ChangeDate, TotalQty
  FROM Data.Inventory
  WHERE ItemID = 1
  ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC;

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_Inventory_Valid_Dates_Sequence". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "Data.Inventory".
The statement has been terminated.


SELECT ChangeDate,
  ChangeQty,
  TotalQty,
  PreviousChangeDate,
  PreviousTotalQty
FROM Data.Inventory ORDER BY ChangeDate;

ChangeDate              ChangeQty   TotalQty    PreviousChangeDate      PreviousTotalQty
----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- -----
2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 10          10          NULL                    NULL
2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 5           15          2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 10
2009-01-04 00:00:00.000 3           18          2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 15
2009-01-05 00:00:00.000 -4          14          2009-01-04 00:00:00.000 18


-- try to change a single row, all updates must fail
UPDATE Data.Inventory SET ChangeQty = ChangeQty + 2 WHERE InventoryID = 3;
UPDATE Data.Inventory SET TotalQty = TotalQty + 2 WHERE InventoryID = 3;
-- try to delete not the last row, all deletes must fail
DELETE FROM Data.Inventory WHERE InventoryID = 1;
DELETE FROM Data.Inventory WHERE InventoryID = 3;

-- the right way to update

DECLARE @IncreaseQty INT;
SET @IncreaseQty = 2;
UPDATE Data.Inventory SET ChangeQty = ChangeQty + CASE WHEN ItemID = 1 AND ChangeDate = '20090103' THEN @IncreaseQty ELSE 0 END,
  TotalQty = TotalQty + @IncreaseQty,
  PreviousTotalQty = PreviousTotalQty + CASE WHEN ItemID = 1 AND ChangeDate = '20090103' THEN 0 ELSE @IncreaseQty END
WHERE ItemID = 1 AND ChangeDate >= '20090103';

SELECT ChangeDate,
  ChangeQty,
  TotalQty,
  PreviousChangeDate,
  PreviousTotalQty
FROM Data.Inventory ORDER BY ChangeDate;

ChangeDate              ChangeQty   TotalQty    PreviousChangeDate      PreviousTotalQty
----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------
2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 10          10          NULL                    NULL
2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 7           17          2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 10
2009-01-04 00:00:00.000 3           20          2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 17
2009-01-05 00:00:00.000 -4          16          2009-01-04 00:00:00.000 20
```

Copied from [my blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/01/23/denormalizing-to-enforce-business-rules-running-totals.aspx)